# How to make translated taxonomy terms correctly be shown in a view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I wonder how to make a multilingual taxonomy term show up in view results.

I'm using Drupal 7. To get my terms translated, I'm using the setting `Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated`. Next, I can edit the term, use the tab *Translation*, and add a translation for the name in Deutsch (and save it afterwards).

But when I then try to create a view to displays these terms(category), they get displayed for both the Deutsch and the English terms. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you installed https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [i18nviews](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) Modules

> Translate views using Internationalization. This is a work in progress
>   and not all Views properties can be translated yet.